# How to save the state of an item in a listview android

Tags: android

How will i go about saving the state of a listview item during scrolling, so that the recycler does not use it when displaying the next row being. i basically have a listview with 4 textviews and one of the textview is displayed based on a condition, derived from a database. For clarity sake, i will call that dependant textview "A".

my problem is that, simplest case: if "A" is being displayed for only the first item or any other row in the list and its not displayed anywhere else, when scrolling, "A"  is displayed on other rows that should not have it. i understand the concept of listview reusing rows, but i can't figure out how to save it on an item, so it doesn't get used in another row.  Here is a simplified code with just 2 textview:

```
  holder.viewItemName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameId);
  holder.viewdescriptionStatus = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.viewdescriptionId);

    int namecolumn = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.NAME); 
    String name = c.getString(namecolumn);

    holder.viewItemName.setText(name);

    int description = c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.description);
    String descriptionstatus = c.getString(description);


    /*problem am having here*/
    if(description != null){
    holder.viewdescriptionStatus.setText("description available");
        holder.viewdescriptionStatus.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }
```

as you can see, am using a viewHolder, but i have come to realise that viewHolder doesn't hold the logic as well. i don't know how to save the state of the holder.viewdescriptionStatus based on that condition. Most of the examples i have seen are based on checkboxes. Please anyone with ideas?.. it will be really appreciated.

P.S : i am using bindView() and newView() since i am using an SQLdatabase and SimpleCursorAdapter. i have the same issue with clicking, but i want to solve the scrolling part first. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
holder.viewdescriptionStatus.setText(description != null ? "description available" : "");
```

Comment: hey thanks, it works nicely. but please one more thing, in case of next time, if i have different text colors, will this work? viewdescription.setTextColor(description.equals("description available") ? Color.BLUE : "");  viewdescription.setTextColor(description.equals("something else") ? Color.RED : "");